# Let $F_n$ converge to $F$ uniformly on all of $\Bbb{R}$, show that $\int F_n$ need not converge to $\int F$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $F_n$ converge to $F$ uniformly on all of $\Bbb{R}$, show that $\int F_n$ need not converge to $\int F$.

I know that this is true when $F_n$ converges on $[a,b]$.

I believe that it fails if the interval is all $\Bbb{R}$. Please explain.

Comment: Your question has a clear title, now it just needs a body! As part of the rules of the site, we require you to provide some of your thoughts/attempts in the process of trying to solve the problem. For example, did you try any simple examples that failed? Can you see why, if you replace $\Bbb{R}$ with a compact interval $[a, b]$, the conclusion actually turns out to be true? Also, which integral are you working with? If you leave your question as is, it will likely be voted down and/or closed by the community.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: Apologies for the original question, I added in some of my thoughts to the body. Thanks for letting me know the etiquette for asking questions here!

Comment: Indicator functions are usually the key to these.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look at the following sequence of functions:

\begin{equation}
F_n(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} \qquad x\in [0,n],\\
0\qquad  else
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$(1/n)\chi[0,n]$ converges uniformly to 0 but $\int f_n(x)$=1 for any fixed n